# OpenMusic does not play audio

Tags: audio, lisp, common-lisp, midi, pulseaudio

I'm using OpenMusic for the first time on Linux Mint 19.2; and I'm having issues getting any sound out of it from MIDI.

I have it set to Pulse Audio for output, and the PA Volume Control is open and above-other-windows, so I can see whether there's an output to it even if it's silenced. It's not muted, it's just dead silent. When I press the Play button on a note or measure, I still get nothing.

I've set MIDI out to timidity, and verified that it's set to use Pulse Audio. Am I missing something here, like a library or a sound font? How do I change that?

To get the obvious out of the way, my speakers are plugged in and on with the sound up; and other software has no issues with playback. I can play audio if it's from a file like an Ogg Vorbis, so this is likely MIDI related.

Comment: Did you try to ask on IRC, Discord, reddit… ?

Comment: @Ehvince I don't do social media.